# What is the best way to display a list of images of varying widths with Rails and a jQuery fading animation?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

On my site, in the foot of each page, I have a collection of images. This collection fades through to another collection after 7.5 seconds.

The problem is that the images can be of varying widths and I need to figure out how many to put in each collection based on the width of each of the images.

My site is 960 pixels wide in total, each image will need to have a right-hand margin, say 15 pixels. So, if I have a collection of 7 images (assuming the last image in the collection has no right-hand margin), I am looking at a total permitted width of 870 pixels.

I can retrieve the width of each of the images so now I need a way to put them together into a collection that has its own div with an id for me to get hold of and fade through with jQuery.

The following code is working for images of the same width.

JS:

```
<% @logo_group_size = 7 %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  <% unless (@logos || Logo.order(:position)).empty? %>
    var logo_sets = [<%= (@logos || Logo.order(:position)).in_groups_of(@logo_group_size, false).collect{|x| (@logos || Logo.order(:position)).in_groups_of(@logo_group_size, false).index(x)}.join(', ') %>];
    var logo_sets_max = <%= (@logos || Logo.order(:position)).in_groups_of(@logo_group_size, false).length - 1 %>;
    var logo_set_index = 0;
    function fadeLogoSets() {
      $("#logo_set_" + logo_sets[logo_set_index]).fadeOut();
      if (logo_set_index < logo_sets_max) { logo_set_index += 1; } else { logo_set_index = 0; }
      $("#logo_set_" + logo_sets[logo_set_index]).fadeIn();
      setTimeout("fadeLogoSets()" , 7500);
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
      setTimeout("fadeLogoSets()", 7500);
    });
  <% end %>
</script>
```

View:

```
<% unless (@logos || Logo.order(:position)).empty? %>
  <% maximum_width = (960 - ((@logo_group_size - 1) * 15)) %>
  <div class="logos">
    <h2>Logos</h2>
    <% (@logos || Logo.order(:position)).in_groups_of(@logo_group_size, false).each_with_index do |logo_set, index| %>
      <% set_width = 0 %>
      <%= content_tag(:div, :id => "logo_set_#{index}", :style => (index.zero? ? "display: block;" : "display: none;")) do %>
        <% logo_set.each_with_index do |logo, index| %>
          <% set_width += MiniMagick::Image.open(("http://#{request.env["HTTP_HOST"]}" + logo.image.home.to_s))["width"].to_i %>
          <% image_options = {} %>
          <% image_options.merge!({:style => "margin-right: 0px;"}) if index == (@logo_group_size - 1) %>
          <% if logo.link.blank? %>
            <%= image_tag(logo.image.home, image_options) %>
          <% else %>
            <%= link_to(image_tag(logo.image.home, image_options), logo.link, {:target => "_blank"}) %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I do understand that this question is somewhat subjective.

Comment: Have you considered just forcing a max width for each image instead of trying to match them properly?  That solution could be done CSS with no extra javascript needed.  Say like 

    .logos img { max-width: 120px; }